# Download power bi report without rendering

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I have created a ssrs report with parameters and published it in the server. I want the file to be downloaded without rendering the file. Does anyone know how to achieve to download the power bi report builder output file without rendering the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the report definition file in Power BI Report Server/SSRS in two ways. In the service:

[image]

And on the SSRS/PBIRS, find the report and select the download option

[image]

These files are the report definition (RDL) files, not the rendered versions. You can then use these in Power BI Report Builder or SSDT to alter them.